# Why is Frodo so strongly drawn to Minas Morgul?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, adaptation-comparison

At around 56 minutes into the Extended Edition of *The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King*, Frodo is heavily drawn to Minas Morgul, the lair of the Witch-king of Angmar, only narrowly being pulled back by Gollum and Sam.

Presumably it's the power of the Ring that's pulling him towards Minas Morgul, but why would the Ring be so strongly drawn to the Witch-king when it's usually only bent on returning to its master in Mordor? Did Tolkien ever elaborate further on what the Ring was "thinking" in this scene?

Comment: A lot of your questions recently seem to take the film and expect something similar from the books. I understand one can expect some form of consistency but the two works are best considered separate, as two different canons. In many cases scenes are greatly dramatised, and while asking whether things were in the books, it can sometimes drag away from you main question. Would answering "No it's not" be sufficient? Most likely not. Would answering why from a film only point of view be sufficient? I'd also imagine not. It raises the possibility of two questions and your post becoming too broad.

Comment: @Edlothiad My "main question" is as outlined at the bottom - how similar that scene is to the books, which I don't think is a strange question to ask. The movies mostly echo the books with very few divergences, and in any case, it is a valid question in and of itself to ask how the source material differs from the adaptation. If the answer really was "it's different" then that would be an acceptable answer, but a good answerer could easily go further and provide the relevant passages about that scene from the books to show exactly how they differ.

Comment: You have in fact just answered with such an answer, so I'm unsure why you ever felt the need to type out the contentions above.

Comment: I contend with the idea that there are very few divergences, I think there are very many significant divergences, in fact some so large that you ask about the final film yet my answer comes from the second volume. It is indeed a valid question, as I say so in my comment, I'm merely saying you're treading on the boundaries of asking two questions. One is a scene comparison between two forms of media. The other is an explanation of why a scene occurs in a film. If the explanation of why the scene occurs is of no interest to you, then that might be better reflected in the title.

Comment: @Edlothiad So you typed all those words on the premise that the title doesn't fully reflect the question in the body? The title has never been the definitive record of what a question is, that's what the body is for, and I don't believe the inconsistent title was worth a downvote, but fixed for you regardless. I have made the question less of an adaptation comparison and asked what the actual reason, from either source, it would be that Frodo is so drawn to Minas Morgul.

Comment: I never downvoted the question, I'm not sure why you would assume I would. I might be nitpicky but I'm not petty... I think the question is fine as an adaptation comparison, I think the question is fine as an explanation, both is toeing the line of broadness. That's all I said. I am in fact one of the upvotes.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

#### UPDATE

<sub>As pointed out in the comments, I seemed to have missed one part of the text in which the slight alteration suggested below is in fact false, and the alteration is rather significantly minor or non-existent. The answer at the time of updating had 13 upvotes for the below stunted and, in hindsight, incomplete answer</sub>

The Ring was indeed drawn to the Nine in some way and seemed to urge Frodo towards the tower. As it had been from shortly after they left Ithilien.

> As soon as the great Cross-roads had been passed, the weight of [his burden], almost forgotten in Ithilien, had begun to grow once more. Now, feeling the way become steep before his feet, he looked wearily up; and then he saw it, even as Gollum had said that he would: the city of the Ringwraiths.
>
> <sub>The Two Towers, Book IV, Chapter 8: The Stairs of Cirith Ungol</sub>

As the passage goes on the Ring appears almost desperate to return to the servants of its Master, physically and emotionally hindering Frodo

> The luminous tower fascinated him, and he fought the desire that was on him to run up the gleaming road towards its gate. At last with an effort he turned back, and as he did so, he felt the Ring resisting him, dragging at the chain about his neck; and his eyes too, as he looked away, seemed for the moment to have been blinded

The scene seems to have been similar to that in which is portrayed in the film. Frodo in the film however gets further than he does in the books, crossing the threshold of the bridge before Sam drags him back, as opposed to catch a falling Frodo. Frodo also hurries and totters towards the Tower in the books as compared to the rather slow stumble of the film.

> Frodo felt his senses reeling and his mind darkening. Then suddenly, as if some force were at work other than his own will, he began to hurry, tottering forward, his groping hands held out.... Both Sam and Gollum ran after him. Sam caught his master in his arms, as he stumbled and almost fell, right on the threshold of the bridge.
> <sub>ibid.</sub>

Another change from the film is the timing of when the gates open, as illustrated below. Frodo, Sam and Gollum climb above the bridge to a height before the light signal rises from the Tower and the Army issues from it. This is where the below answer gets confused with the scene in the film.

---

---

This seems to be a rather bizarre alteration from what is a far more simple series of steps in the books. Frodo, at the same point in the books, is fatigued rather than drawn to Minas Morgul. He is however encouraged by Gollum to carry on as Gollum senses something sinister is abound.

> ‘I must rest a while, Sam,’ whispered Frodo. ‘It’s heavy on me, Sam lad, very heavy. I wonder how far I can carry it? Anyway I must rest before we venture on to that.’[...]
>
> ‘Sssh! ssh!’ hissed Gollum hurrying back to them. ‘Sssh!’ **His fingers were on his lips and he shook his head urgently. Tugging at Frodo’s sleeve, he pointed towards the path; but Frodo would not move.**
>
> ‘Not yet,’ he said, ‘not yet.’ **Weariness and more than weariness oppressed him; it seemed as if a heavy spell was laid on his mind and body.** ‘I must rest,’ he muttered.
>
> <sub>The Two Towers, Book IV, Chapter 8: The Stairs of Cirith Ungol</sub>

The final emphasised line seems to be where the writers for the film drew their main inspiration from. That some form of spell drew Frodo to Minas Morgul and the Witch-king. This is further emphasised later when Frodo's eyes are drawn to Lord of the Nine.

> “Now he was drawing near the bridge below, and **Frodo’s staring eyes followed him, unable to wink or to withdraw.** [...] Here, yes here indeed was the haggard king whose cold hand had smitten down the Ring-bearer with his deadly knife. The old wound throbbed with pain and a great chill spread towards Frodo’s heart.
>
> **Even as these thoughts pierced him with dread and held him bound as with a spell**, the Rider halted suddenly, [...] Maybe it was the Ring that called to the Wraith-lord, and for a moment he was troubled, sensing some other power within his valley. This way and that turned the dark head helmed and crowned with fear, sweeping the shadows with its unseen eyes. Frodo waited, like a bird at the approach of a snake, unable to move. **And as he waited, he felt, more urgent than ever before, the command that he should put on the Ring.**
>
> <sub>ibid.</sub>

Answer (score -3):

He was drawn to Minas Morgul because of the eye of Sauron that's the only time Frodo becomes in a possessed state.You want to know another time it happened ? It happened at Osgoliath when the witch king was flying on that dragon.The part with the ring telling him to walk in a certain direction don't fit to well since Gollum was guiding them.Also the nearer he got to Mount Doom the greater the burden of the ring became.Aragorn and the soldiers had to create a diversion to draw the eye of Sauron off from Frodo by fighting right in front of the Black Gate.Its got to do with Saurons powers and every time that eye was facing in Frodos direction or when the ring was put on also in that Palantir that Pippin wanted to peak in Saurons power was so great it knocked him out Aragorn had to grab it.Thats my opinion thou

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You could improve this answer by editing it to include one or more relevant quotes from the source material or author as supporting evidence. A quote from Tolkien himself would be especially good, as the question specifically asked about that.